# How can I make 5 digit alpha numeric sequential string

Tags: php, logic

Can i get logic to make 5 digit alpha numeric sequential string.

if number between 00001-99999, we can show the same number, but when reach 99999 it should  show A00001 instead of 100000. Also after A9999 it should be B0001.

Do you have any logic to do this.

Comment: Ranging from A to Z? And actuall shouldn't it be B0000 after A9999?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

Comment: What do you want after ZZZZZ?

Comment: You can save big values till ZZZZZ. You don't need think about it.

Comment: does the sequence have to be like that or would you be fine having 99 followed by 9A and thus the biggest number being ZZZZZ but the 10001st Number would be 7pt? You would have the same amount of possible combinations but in an accurate sequence rather than the one you described.

Comment: +1 ive been mind boggling this for too long lol i can see its going to ruin my day

Comment: @shemeermali Please provide feedback on my comment, people are starting to freak out :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function seq4($input){

        $i=0;$var = 'A';

        $max_lenght     =  5;       $length         =  strlen($input);
                if($length>$max_lenght){            while($input >= 10000){
                $input = $input - 10000;                
                $i++;           }

            $i=$i-9;
                        while($i > 1){                 
                $i--;         
                $var++.'';
             }

             $bal_lenght    = $max_lenght - ($str_lenght = strlen($var));  
             $string        = $var.str_pad($input, $bal_lenght, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
             $string_lenght = strlen($string);
             return ($string_lenght>$max_lenght)?false:$string;                             } else {
             return str_pad($input, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);      }   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this that converts the input string to base 10 ([0-9]), increases the value by 1, converts back to base 36 ([a-z0-9]) and returns the new value. It also pads the value to 5 characters for numeric values less than 10000.

```
function do_the_thing($string){
    return str_pad(base_convert(base_convert($string,36,10)+1,10,36),5,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Testing with

```
echo do_the_thing('a0000');
```

Returns 'a0001'.

Some results after testing:

```
99999 -> 9999a
a9999 -> a999a
zzzzz -> 100000
```

Not 100% what you're looking for but quite close.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were asking

```
$input  = '10099999'; 

$i=0;
while($input >= 100000)
{

$input = $input - 100000;
$i++;

}

if($i < 1)
{
echo $input;
}
else
{

     if($i >26)
     {
         $letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
         $k="";
         $j=0;

         while($i > 26)
         {
            $i=$i-26;
            $j++;
         }

         for($l=0;$l<$j;$l++)
         {
             $k=$k."".$letters[25];
         }

         if($input == 0)
            $input = "0000";
         $input2="";
         for($l=$i;$l>$i;$l--)
         {

             if($input >= (9999/(pow(10,$j))))
                $input = $input / 10;

         }

         $kt=$k."".$letters[$i]."".$input;


         echo "".($k)."".$letters[$i]."".floor($input/pow(10,$j));

     }
     else
     {
       $s="";

       $letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
       if($input == 0)
       {
          echo $letters[$i-1]."0000";
       }
       else
       {
          echo $letters[$i-1]."".$input;
       }
     }

}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/071650abe0f81a100efcb9db021830ab138d032e)

Comment: This is what i need, but it not working properly. some errors are there.

Comment: Could you mention what errors so that I can clear it

Comment: Can you test "2700000", it' give "ZB0" instead of "AA001"

Comment: Hi Krishna,

I posted a solution below as answer. It almost working fine. Thank you for the help. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your interest is getting a sequence of aplhanumeric digits, ranging from 0 to ZZZZZ and you do not care about the order described, you could actually use base 36 for your numbers.

You can use PHP's own [base_convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) method which allows for a [base](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/numbbase.htm) up to 36 and uses a-z if it hits the range of numbers to represent your value.

So for example do [this](https://eval.in/144463):

```
<?php
$number = '12332';
echo base_convert($number, 10, 36);
```

This will give you `9ik` as a value.

You can use simple integers and increase them, then use base_convert ot get the sequential number you wanted.

So just do this:

```
$input  = 'a053'; // your alphanumeric input number
$base10 = intval(base_convert($input, 36, 10)); // converted to base10
$base10++; // increase number
$output = base_convert($base10, 10, 36); // convert back to alphanumerical
```

I'll pack it in a neat [function](https://eval.in/144482) for you:

```
<?php
/**
 * increases given base36 number $current and returns it as base 36 
 */
function giveMyNumber($current = 0) {
  $base36 = '00000';
  if($current > 0) {
    $base10 = base_convert($current, 36, 10);
    $base10++;
    if($base > 60466175) {
      throw new \Exception('Maximum reached!');
    }
    $base36 = base_convert($base10, 10, 36);
  }

  return $base36;
}

echo giveMyNumber('45Z');
```

Comment: Please Read the question properly. OP asked `Can i get logic to make 5 digit alpha numeric sequential string.`

Comment: @krishna Please read my answer properly. I stated that he could use simple integers, increase them and use base_convert to get the alphanumeric string he wants. Nothing wrong with my answer. Still, i'll clarify for you

Comment: the problem is When using base_convert it changes the number < 99999 also

Comment: What your answer does is changes `a053` to `a054`, which OP does not want.If i am correct OP needs is from `100000` it should start displaying from `A00001` and **numbers should be in 5 digits**.

Comment: @krishna if he wants to use alphanumeric numbers then that is correct. 99 is not just 99 anymore. 9 is still 9, but 10 is ultimately > 10 because after 9 it is not 10 but a. Surely, the sequence he pointed out is different, but i am pretty sure, all he wants is alphanumeric numbers and he just didn't know too much about it and therefore thought after 99 it schould be 100 and only after 99999 it should be A0000

Comment: @krishna we are both making assumptions here. Thou yours are based on what OP asked specificly, i assume it is the good old XY problem and hopefully provided a valid answer.

Comment: May be if OP had misunderstood the series. But we cannot come to decision until OP clears it properly.

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
function gencode($prefix='A',$s = '00000000', $n){
    return $prefix.substr($s,0, strlen($s) - strlen($n)).$n;
}
```

Where `n` is your `(last +1)` item, just needs some changes like verify the length on `$s` to change `$n` to 0 and prefix to 'B'

Comment: Thats not what the OP wants one could just use sprint() instead with better results